# Windows server not receiving request

Tags: iis, plesk, windows-server

I have a windows server running `Plesk`. I was having some issue with `port` usage so I ran the command `netsh http delete iplisten ipaddress=::` and I had multiple apps running on that server that I don't even remember the configuration of and they all stopped working. I restarted the server hoping that it would restart the services but to no luck. I ran `netsh http add` command to again listen `::` but its not helping. Anyone knows what I did wrong here?

Comment: "I had multiple apps running on that server that I don't even remember the configuration of and they all stopped working." Then you'd better rebuild the server and keep good records of what you configure. It's just a waste of time to work on a messy environment.

Comment: Did you get any error messages? For example: in the Event viewer.